# Are moderators allowed to delete questions on here

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about problems I was having with my wifi on raspbian, on my Raspberry Pi 3, and my odd discovery that the 'find' command couldn't find certain files regarding wpa_supplicant.

My question had several answers and it had technical information in it which I would have preferred to have kept around. However it is no longer on here because it was deleted, probably by a moderator. The information in my question is now lost.

Are moderators allowed to delete questions on here and if so what are the reasons justifying deletions.

Comment: As per the answers this was autodeleted.  I've undeleted it so you can retrieve whatever information it is you wanted (deleted posts are visible to the owner, but only for 60 days). Note it will be subject to autodeletion again as per the criteria below (which is desirable -- there is nothing there of interest to posterity generally and there is no point in keeping clutter; this isn't cloud storage for personal notes, etc.).

Comment: @goldilocks Thank you for doing this! This was important to me and I appreciate it. I've just retrieved the information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm afraid your question was aged into deletion by the [Community user](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) on June 9th 2016, rather than consciously deleted by a moderator. The relevant deletion process is:

> If the question was closed more than 9 days ago, and ...
>
> ```
> not closed as a duplicate
> has a score of 0 or less
> is not locked
> has no answers with a score > 0
> has no accepted answer
> has no pending reopen votes
> has not been edited in the past 9 days
> ```
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. These are "abandoned closed",
>   and are termed as RemoveAbandonedClosed.
>
> This check is run every day across all sites.

I'm taking a look at the question and its associated answers just now, and it appears that the issue you had resolved itself under non-replicable mysterious circumstances. To my mind that minimises its use to the wider community as we can no longer establish exactly what the problem was and, as such, the Community user was justified in deleting it.

Comment: Thank you for actually looking at my deleted entry. It makes me feel better that it wasn't permanently deleted from your database and that it went through a standard process before being deleted.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Yes, moderators are allowed to delete questions - it's actually part of moderation. As for particular reasons: see below.

This [meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/284388) got it pretty much covered, how and why posts are deleted and what implications are attached. So bullet 2 seems to answer your question:

> 2. **Moderators** can delete any post instantly.

... seems to answer, however, as it is not true. Your post was automatically deleted by the system as it was closed and met the criteria listed:

> 7. The system will automatically delete closed (not as a duplicate), unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no positively scored or accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed 9 or more days ago and haven't been edited in the past 9 days.

Please note that a deleted question can be un-deleted and re-opened if they *add value* to the site - if necessary after improving or editing the question. If you think that this should be the case here, give us a ping but please consider the last paragraph of [goobering's answer](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/904/19949).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that I can request a review of deleted questions. This is important to me because I want to avoid losing technical information that I spent time working on and typing up on stackexchange if possible.